# How does the 'window' object become the global object of a front end JS script?

Tags: javascript, object, window, global

Hello Stackoverflow community!

I kind of know what the window and global object is, but I would like to know how this works under the hood / behind the scene.

How does the browser add this window object as the global object to our script and why?

Thanks

Comment: Have you browsed Chromium and Firefox source code?

Comment: not yet, I'm still a noob trying to find some grip :/

Comment: See https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/, https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/

Comment: Ok I think I got the answer. As we all know, functions are objects which are executable. All objects in our JS Script will be 'packaged' inside a global object, which is normally the 'window' object on the front end. After that, the global function will be executed. - Is this in any way correct or just totally wrong lol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creation phaase a.k.a Global Execution Context.

When running code at the base level, JS engine will automatically do the following:

1. Create a global object, which means all your code will sit inside of this global object. If you are using in browser environment, this global object is window. It all depends on where do you execute your JS code.
2. Create a special variable called "**this**". At the global level, "this" would equal the Global (window) Object.
3. A reference to the outer environment if there is one. This means where something sits physically in the code you write and what's around it, a.k.a Lexical Environment